# What's the difference between ε-dense and dense?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Im reading Carothers' Real Analysis, 1ed. Here is the definition of dense,
[image]

and ε-dense is claimed in topic of total boundness,
[image].

What's the difference between ε-dense and dense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A set is dense if it's $\varepsilon$-dense for **every** $\varepsilon\gt0$. For example, the set $\mathbb Z$ of all integers is $\varepsilon$-dense in the set $\mathbb R$ of real numbers for every $\varepsilon\gt\frac12$, but it's not $\varepsilon$-dense in $\mathbb R$ for any $ \varepsilon\lt\frac12$, so it's not dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Don't you mean $\tfrac12$ rather than $1$?

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks for the correction!

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}$ or 1?

Comment: should be 1 right?

Comment: I first wrote $1$ but corrected it to $\frac12$ after Erick Wong pointed out my mistake.

Comment: I see. So "ε > $\frac{1}{2}$" will satisfy the property that $B_ε$(x) ∩ A ≠ empty for every x∈M, right?

Comment: Sorry for late confirmation of answer. Real analysis is a little bit difficult to understand. One year ago, I cannot understand most of them while now I can. Some part of. Thanks, bof.