# $\epsilon$-Density of Truncated Span

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

This is a sort-of follow-up to [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3443286/density-of-truncated-partial-sums-of-basis/3443292?noredirect=1#comment7078647_3443292)

Suppose that $X$ is a Banach space with $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ satsfying:
$$
\overline{
  \operatorname{span}_{i \in I} \{x_i\}
}
=
X.
$$

Is it then true that, for every $N>1$, there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that for every
$$
X_N\triangleq \left\{
\sum_{j=0}^s k_j x_j:\, s \in \mathbb{N} , 0\leq s\leq N, \, k_1,\dots,k_s \in \mathbb{R},\,
 x_j \in \{x_i\}_{i \in I}
\right\}
$$
is [$\epsilon$-dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/651090/whats-the-difference-between-%CE%B5-dense-and-dense) in $X$ for some $\epsilon>0$; that is, for every $y \in X$ there exists some $z \in X_N$ satisfying
$$
\|y-z\|_X \leq \epsilon
.
$$

*Connection to density:* If $\operatorname{span}_{j\in I} \{x_j\}$ is $\epsilon$-dense in $X$ for every $\epsilon >0$; ie: it is [dense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set).

If this is not the case, is there a "reasonable" sufficient condition on $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ for the truncation result to hold?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. For a simple example let $X=c_0$ and $x_i=\delta_i$ which is the sequence consting of zeros except for the $i$th component which is equal to $1$. Every element of $X_N$ has only $N+1$ components different from $0$ and for any $\varepsilon>0$ the sequence starting with $N+2$ components equal to $2\varepsilon$ and zero components then has distance $2\varepsilon$ to $X_N$.

Comment: Do you believe there to be a "reasonable" sufficient condition on $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ for this to hold?

Comment: The set $\lbrace t x:i:i\in I, t\in \mathbb R\rbrace$ could be dense -- but of course one is then very far away from a basis. I think that the example for $c_0$ is quite typical for a basis.

Comment: I don't see how $\{tx_i: i \in I, t \in \mathbb{R}\}\subseteq X_N$ can be dense but the latter can't?

Comment: If $X_1=\lbrace tx_i:i\in I, t\in\mathbb R\rbrace$ is dense then of course all $X_N$ are dense. For example, there are so-called *supercyclic* operaors $T$ having orbits $x_i=T^i(x_0)$ such that $X_1=\lbrace t T^i(x_0): t\in\mathbb R, i\in\mathbb N\rbrace$ is dense.

Comment: In operator-theoretic language, MrMMS seems to be asking if there exists something between cyclic and supercyclic operators (and therefore cyclic and supercyclic vectors).

This is an interesting question, since cyclic vectors are well-understood and supercyclic (and even more hypercylic) operators are very well-studied.